# grunt-http-server stops running

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to use the grunt-http-server

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-http-server

I follow the example that is on the link

```
'http-server': {

    'dev': {

        // the server root directory 
        root: apps,

        // the server port 
        // can also be written as a function, e.g. 
        // port: function() { return 8282; } 
        port: 8282,


        // the host ip address 
        // If specified to, for example, "127.0.0.1" the server will  
        // only be available on that ip. 
        // Specify "0.0.0.0" to be available everywhere 
        host: "127.0.0.1",

        cache: 10,
        showDir : true,
        autoIndex: true,

        // server default file extension 
        ext: "html",

        // run in parallel with other tasks 
        runInBackground: true,

        // specify a logger function. By default the requests are 
        // sent to stdout. 
        logFn: function(req, res, error) { }

    }

},
```

and when I run the task

```
grunt http-server:dev
```

the task is running but it stops

```
Running "http-server:dev" (http-server) task
Server running on  127.0.0.1:8282
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server

Done, without errors.
```

and when I visit 127.0.0.1:8282 I am getting a page is not available.
What do I have to do in order the task to keep running and serve my files.

Comment: what is the actual configuration? you're only showing the template. where are the real values? are you setting `runInBackground: true` ?

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `runInBackground: false`.

Because `runInBackground` tells grunt:

- when `true`: to keep running the rest of the tasks.
- when `false`: to stop and wait on the server indefinitely.

In your case, when set to `true`, there is no other task to run, so grunt terminates and takes down with it everything it launched including your server. `true` would be useful if you followed your server start with a `watch` task for example.